# Excel VBA script or macro for linking to new Excel document using a template in it

Tags: templates, excel, vba

I have a small family-operated shop and, in the process of speeding things up and/or automating them, I need help on the following matter (will try to explain as well as possible, since I am at a novice level on this kind of stuff.)

So, in my shop we offer a certain service (taking specific measurements of body dimensions along with weight/sugar levels etc etc). I have created an .xlsx document that contains all required fields and saved it as a template for future use. What I need to do is this:
I want to have a "master" Excel file with the names of our customers. From there, each name when clicked should open a new Excel file, using the aforementioned template, which would eventually be saved as each customer's record. I've tried a script for linking to the template but opening it as a new file (with the template in it) but, the problem is that each time I click on the name on the master file it opens a new document altogether, while I need it to open a new document named after the name in the original cell, with the template in it. As far as I can think, this is the best "automation" I can accomplish. Is it plausible? If so, how can I do it?

---

edit: this is the code, as i found it elsewhere:

```
'File:
'  OfficeTemplate.vbs
'
'Problem:
'  A hyperlink from an Office application to an Office template opens the template,
'    instead of creating a new file.
'  The proposed solution
'    support.microsoft.com/kb/278627
'  did not work.
'
'Solution:
'  Create a hyperlink to a VBS file that starts the process.
'
'Instructions:
'  Copy this VBScript into the same directory of your template.
'  Rename it so that the VBS file name has the name of the template file in front.
'  Example:
'    Template name: test.dotx
'    VBScript name: test.dotx.vbs
'  Create the hyperlink to the VBS file.

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the name of the template
OurName = fso.GetBaseName(WScript.ScriptName)
'Find all files in our directory
For Each File In fso.GetFolder(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)).Files
  'Did we found the template?
  If StrComp(OurName, File.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    'Invoke the default verb
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName(File.Path).InvokeVerb
    'Wait a second to let the application start
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    'Done
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

this is my template:

http://i215.photobucket.com/albums/cc55/psyclone_tread/templ.jpg

this is the master file, just a column with names and one with phone numbers, i want the names to link to each customer's individual file.

http://i215.photobucket.com/albums/cc55/psyclone_tread/master.jpg

Comment: Show your current code.  A new document has no name until you save it, so you can't open a fresh document with a given name.

Comment: agreed with Tim. Post your code and screenshot link of your master and template file.

Comment: i just did, if what i described above is not possible, then i would gladly accept any functioning suggestions!

Comment: @VasilizMoschou if the below answer work for you thats ok, otherwise, could you please translate your sheets to english and upload again. Cant read your language!

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a very simple answer for this. Use VBA instead of VBS, and write code inside your master excel as per following illustration.

When you click on the cell with the name,

`If File.Exists ("YourFolder\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".xlsx") Then
Workbooks.Open("YourFolder\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".xlsx")
Else
WorkBooks.Add(YourTemplate)
Fill in the details already present in the master sheet to new workbook if needed
NewWorkbook.Save("YourFolder\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".xlsx")
End If`

Comment: I think I get the idea (I am only a newbie), but I get an error. The "YourFolder\" section is marked and the error message says: "Compile Error: Invalid Outside Procedure". Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot for your help thus far.